# CCSprite showing weird debug?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, spritebuilder

Has anyone seen this before?

Sprite is an animation created in SpriteBuilder (1.4.9) which is loaded onto the screen and positioned in code.

myFoodAnim = (CCSprite*)[CCBReader load:@"foodAnim64"];

Occasionally I get text overlayed as in the pictures below. This only seems to be happening on older 32bit iphone 5, ipad2 and ipad mini. Not on iphone 5s,6,6+

[Image1](http://www.dexteritydesign.co.uk/SpriteBug01.png)
[Image2](http://www.dexteritydesign.co.uk/SpriteBug02.png)